TypeError when trying to change in for loop using enumerate function input
I am trying to get sorted values from the users but,it doesn't work...
    waiting_list=["sen","ben","john"]
    waiting_list=waiting_list.sort()

    for index,item in enumerate(waiting_list):
        row=F"{index+1}.{item.capitalize()}"
        print(row) 

that code produced the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\test.com\pythonProject1\.venv\begining python file.py", line 4, in <module>
    for index,item in enumerate(waiting_list):
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I excepted to convert the list values to be sequential order and how to convert the proper code feed ?
i am trying convert the list values in sequential orderand produce the essential list .meanwhile it raises the following error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ELCOT\Desktop\test.com\pythonProject1\.venv\begining python file.py", line 4, in <module>
    for index,item in enumerate(waiting_list):
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I excepted to convert the list values to be sequential order and how to convert the proper code feed ?

the sort() method mutates the list object in place and returns none. By reassigning waiting_list you're actually setting it to None. You can either use sorted(), or remove the assignment:
waiting_list = ["sen", "ben", "john"]
waiting_list = sorted(waiting_list)

for index, item in enumerate(waiting_list):
    row = F"{index+1}.{item.capitalize()}"
    print(row)

or:
waiting_list = ["sen", "ben", "john"]
waiting_list.sort()

for index, item in enumerate(waiting_list):
    row = F"{index+1}.{item.capitalize()}"
    print(row)


thank you bruhh
